# EF POCOs as WCF data contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

May team has been doing some refactoring in order to right historical wrongs.
We moved DataContracts and OperationContracts out of the BL layer and in to a separate assembly, we severed dependancies from the interface assembly to the BL objects and are now consuming the services via ChannelFactory instead of generated proxies.

Now we want to begin integrating EF in to our DAL, which supports the BL layer.
Since the EF team is making big conceptual changes with each release (Not that it's a bad thing :)), I'm a little lost.

I want to use EF with POCOs and also make these POCOs the data contracts for the services. There are no updates going back to the DB. Only data coming in to the web server. My issue is that I see all sorts of solutions from different versions of EF, and I don't know what the current best practice is...

Can someone help me get my head around this? What is the current best practice? Are there any special attributes or methods I need to set on my POCOs in order to use them as data contracts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most powerful way to generate your POCOs from EF for transmitting across the wire is to use T4 templating. In fact - if you use .net 4.5, the EF designer now uses a T4 template instead of the usual visual studio codegen.

T4 generated POCOs should be ready to be transmitted across the wire without any attribute additions, but even if they were - changing the T4 template to suit you needs would be trivial.

In terms of best practices I don't think there is one 'answer' out there, and there are different approaches depending on what you need. POCO generation via T4 is in my opinion the best approach for most scenarios though, as you don't need to write any mapping code and you have a POCO library agnostic from it's data layer representation.

Here is the template download

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313

Here is some tutorial/resources

http://sharedtolearn.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/entity-framework-40-and-t4-templates-to.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff717739.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Is there a solution for .net 4 as well? Upgrading production servers to .net 4.5 takes signatures from 20 different managers here and is a 4 month long process, and thats an optimistic scenario with rejects along the path :)

Comment: Yes there is, the links i have provided are all .net 4. If you install the templates via those links it will work with .net 4 and Visual Studio 2010. With VS2012/.net4.5 the only difference is that you get the functionality out of the box and don't have to install anything.